# Why is not permited to access a member function from my local event handler in ActionScript (Flex4)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

My code looks like :

```
private function createExportButton() : void {
        var exportButton : Button = new Button();
        exportButton.label = "Export";
        exportButton.x = 600;
        exportButton.y = 10;
        exportButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function
                                           clickHandler(e : MouseEvent) : void {
            this.export();
        });
        super.addElement(exportButton);
    }
```

The error is:

*
TypeError: Error #1006: export is not a function.   at Function/()[C:\Users\User\Adobe Flash Builder 4\agriculturalAdministration\src\certificate\one\CertificateBuilder1.as:150]
*
Can anyone explain me why this?
Thanks advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`clickHandler()` is not a member function, it does not belong to any class. It is an anonymous function. Therefore, it does not belong to an instance.

However, if I recall correctly, you should be able to refer to variables in the enclosing scope (such as `exportButton`) from within. In that case, you may want to assign the class reference to a variable and use that instead of `this`:

```
var exportButton:Button = new Button();
var this_:SomeClass = this;
...
addEventListener(..., function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this_.export();
});
```

Or, you can just make `clickHandler()` a member function:

```
private function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.export();
}

...
{
    addEventListener(..., clickHandler);
}
```

Comment: Here is the obligatory +1 that the OP forgot to give you..!